# Does "categorically" always mean "without question"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I get the sense that "categorically" can imply "only in the strictest sense."

One way I see it being used as a qualifier: as if to say, according just to the means by which we regularly assign judgment.

This is strangely counter-intuitive use, but I felt it being used that way and that it does convey a distinction.

Comment: What does 'mean' mean? Categorically means things fall into distinct categories and not somewhere between,  things are black and white, there's no vagueness. 'Without question' means you don't have any questions about the answer, meaning there's no doubt. Obviously there's lots of overlap between the two, but vagueness and doubt are not the same thing.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. Please [edit] this to add more examples.

Comment: In practice, this is one of those crap words in English **that means nothing -- absolutely nothing, zilch**.  Politicians add it to sentences to, well, make the sentence longer ... it's essentially like saying **and I really mean it**.  I categorically deny having taken bribes. I categorically insist on a retrial.  Etc.  Totally meaningless.  "Really" or "Truly" sounds common in those sentences so you use "categorically".  If you simply **look in the dictionary** you will see this, it simply means "positively, absolutely".

Comment: Some people care. Some people do not. Which one are you, Joe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of assigning judgement, the term "categorically" can also be used to describe judgement assigned in lieu of quantifiable or empirical standards. It describes a judgement passed subjectively, as opposed to objectively.

The admissions counselor, ignoring the applicant's merits, categorically judged the candidate by his performance in the interview.

This usage is based in the logic of Sir William Hamilton, Bart, who, in the Product of Thoughts and Judgements, referenced the "categorical judgement" of an objective through its qualities.

Comment: This seems to me a very specialised use. In an everyday sense to *categorically deny* something means to deny it absolutely, without reservation. That sense seems to have little to do with categories.

Comment: The question specifically asked if the proposed definition "always" applies to the term. By providing an alternative definition, I was showing that there exists another usage of the term. In determining the validity of an absolute, one must find, or fail to find, an exception to that absolute. I provided an exception.

Comment: What source can you quote for this? It seems unknown to the OED compilers, for both *categorical* and *categorically*. the important point about Kant's *categorical imperative* is that it is the absolute unconditional command of the moral law.

Comment: One of the definitions that you provided above: "1619 J. Hales Let. from Dort in Wks. (1765) III. 121 The praeses signified..that..he was now in the name of the synod to require them to answer categorically, yea or no." also seems to reference categories "yea or no" as a source of non-empirical judgement.

Comment: Thomas, thank you. You have helped me to find basis to my intuiting this precise type of extremely common use exception. I sense that even on an language enthusiasts forum, these nuances get lost or are not welcome!

Answer (score 2):

This is the only meaning of ***categorically*** given in the OED.

> **In a categorical manner; with absolute assertion, absolutely,
>   positively, unconditionally.**
>
> 1603   P. Holland tr. Plutarch Morals 1355   Of this particle or
>   Conjunction Ει, that is to say, If..nothing can be made nor
>   categorically affirmed.
>
> 1619   J. Hales Let. from Dort in Wks. (1765) III. 121   The praeses
>   signified..that..he was now in the name of the synod to require them
>   to answer categorically, yea or no.
>
> 1635   E. Pagitt Christianographie 53   Not one word Categorically,
>   plainly, and distinctly set downe, by which Purgatory is taught.
>
> 1874   H. Sidgwick Methods of Ethics   The categorically imperative
>   function.
>
> 1879   W. E. Gladstone Gleanings Past Years VI. iii. 184   That every
>   cause be resolved categorically by an Aye or a No.